# changing font size and family in mat-select losing focus on selected option

Tags: angular-material, material-design

I've changed font-size to 16px and font family to Ubuntu, that made Angular Material Control mat-select list in a weird format. The option that is selected is not getting focused when opening drop down, also option is getting cut from top and bottom.

See the screenshot attached. In one screenshot, font-size is 14px and in another 16px.[image][image]

Answer (score 0):

How are you changing the font-size? no issues for me with 22px or 28px

my **CSS**:

```
::ng-deep .mat-select-panel .mat-option-text { font-size:28px; }
```

working [stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1ryuus)

[image]